# How to get data from one table and add into another table in C# DataSet?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I have a complex xml file and I read the xml and stored the data into DataSet object. The DataSet holds the following DataTable

```
1.Customer
2.Operation 
3.Account 
4.Card
```

**Customer** DataTable has many column with CustomerId and SerialNo. Others DataTable has SerialNo column common. I need to Add CustomerId Column value into others (Operation,Account and card) DataTable according to SerialNo and need to Store all table data into database. How can I do this, please advise me with example.

Comment: Please show sample data , your tables structure , and also what you try so far , help us to help you

Comment: is your ultimate goal to update those tables in a sql server database or just to update a dataset?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You seem to need help with something. However you also seem to have forgotten to post any details about your system or what you are trying to do. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @Joshua Evensen, my goal to update those tables in a sql server database.

Comment: ya, put more info on the question and ppl will be more apt to help. also i dont know that the fact that System.Data.DataTable is being used is really important. you probably just need to run a query to do what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

**C# Code:**

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            ds.ReadXml(@"D:\Test.xml");               

            DataTable dtstatement = ds.Tables["Statement"];

            foreach (DataRow dr in dtstatement.Rows)
            {
                Statement statement = new Statement();
                statement.IdClient = Convert.ToInt32(dr["IdClient"].ToString());
                statement.StatementNo = Convert.ToInt32(dr["StatementNo"].ToString());

                DataRow[] selectedCards = ds.Tables["card"].Select(string.Format("StatementNo = {0}", statement.StatementNo));
                if (selectedCards.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in selectedCards)
                    {
                        Card card = new Card();
                        card.IdClient = statement.IdClient;
                        card.CardNo = item["cardNo"].ToString();
                    }
                }
                DataRow[] selectedAccounts = ds.Tables["Account"].Select("StatementNo = " + statement.StatementNo);
                if (selectedAccounts.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in selectedAccounts)
                    {
                        Account account = new Account();
                        account.IdClient = statement.IdClient;
                        account.AccountNo = item["AccountNo"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Statements>
 <Statement>
    <StatementNo>1</StatementNo>
    <IdClient>101</IdClient>
    <Cards>
        <card>
            <StatementNo>1</StatementNo>
            <cardNo>123456</cardNo>
        </card>
        <card>
            <StatementNo>1</StatementNo>
            <cardNo>1234567</cardNo>
        </card>
    </Cards>
    <Accounts>
        <Account>
            <StatementNo>1</StatementNo>
            <AccountNo>123456</AccountNo>
        </Account>
        <Account>
            <StatementNo>1</StatementNo>
            <AccountNo>1234567</AccountNo>
        </Account>
    </Accounts>
</Statement>
 <Statement>
    <StatementNo>2</StatementNo>
    <IdClient>102</IdClient>
    <Cards>
        <card>
            <StatementNo>2</StatementNo>
            <cardNo>12345678</cardNo>
        </card>         
    </Cards>
  </Statement>
</Statements>
```